# Longtable with file contents not compiling

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable, filecontents

I am trying get a simple table like this:

[image]

I am using `longtable` as I have data in a `.dat` files.

Can you help me successfully generate the table using the importation of data from a file?

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data133.dat}
X   2,7 3,6 2,5 3,5 3,3 2,2 5,1 6,2 8,1 6,4 4,8 5,8 9,5 9,9 9,4 8,9 8,8 6,9 7,4 4,4
Y   +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header, rows = {X,Y},
]{data133.dat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are your tables going to be **long**? or just wide? If they are short, then `longtable` does not help.

Comment: I would like the table wide just like that shown in the graphic.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I edited the code slightly, to bring it into conformance with revised (2016-11-07) `readarray` preferred package syntax.  In particular, I no longer can assume each digested record ends with a space.  But more importantly, the `mydata` array is no longer a `nx1` 2-D array, but is a true 1-D array of size `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One requirement is that the field width in `\specialtable` contains a number of columns greater than or equal to the max. number expected in your data files.

I took the liberty of setting the table content in math mode.

EDITED (Dec 2016) to remove expectation of blank space at the end of each file record.  Upgraded to preferred syntax of 2016-11-07 `readarray` release.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt, 
  top={\dimexpr120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data133.dat}
X   2,7 3,6 2,5 3,5 3,3 2,2 5,1 6,2 8,1 6,4 4,8 5,8 9,5 9,9 9,4 8,9 8,8 6,9 7,4 4,4
Y   +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
\end{filecontents*}%
\newcommand\digest[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\mydata[#1]}%
  \expandafter\digestaux\tmp{} \relax%
}
\def\digestaux#1 #2\relax{$#1$\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\digestauxB#2\relax\fi}
\def\digestauxB#1\relax{&\digestaux#1\relax}
\newcommand\specialtable[1]{%
  \noindent
  \tabcolsep=4pt\relax%
  \readrecordarray{#1}\mydata%
% THE FOLLOWING LINE MUST ALLOW FOR THE MAX. NUMBER OF COLUMNS EXPECTED
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline\digest{1}\\\hline\digest{2}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\specialtable{data133.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can add dummy header, the following appears to work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
% \usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt,
% top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data133.dat}
Z   x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
X   2,7 3,6 2,5 3,5 3,3 2,2 5,1 6,2 8,1 6,4 4,8 5,8 9,5 9,9 9,4 8,9 8,8 6,9 7,4 4,4
Y   +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  +1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
\end{filecontents*}%

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

% \pgfplotstableset{
% begin table={\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}},
% end table={\end{longtable}\egroup},
% }

% \pgfplotstableset{
% begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}\begin{longtable},
% end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
% }


\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space, empty header, read comma as period,
  outfile=\jobname.out.tex,
  columns/Z/.style={
    column name={},
    assign cell content/.code={%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}
    },
  },
]{data133.dat}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you go about adding the lines?  Thanks!

Comment: I used pgfplotstable for the first time. Here I tampered with your data file by manually adding a row of headers. Don't know how to simulate that from only using pgfplotstable.

Comment: the `outfile=\jobname.out.tex` is a debugging left-over it allows to see the LaTeX code produced by pgfplotstable.

Comment: I tried something like  `columns/0/.style` but it didn't work hence the extra add header row to have `columns/Z` available.